# Why form with few inputs in it, without any buttons, doesn't submit?

Tags: html, forms

Why form with only one text input (without any buttons) will submit, but with two text inputs won't?

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-submitting-ztqpz?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

Add a submit button on each form (few inputs too) and it will work both with button and pressing enter

```
<div class="panel"> 
   <div class="panel-title">Few inputs</div>
      <form action=".">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Click</button>
        <output name="result" />
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have a submit button, but it is outside the form, for some reason (exactly `z-index` issue). I am trying to find a way to submit a form by Enter without specifying the `form` attribute on the button itself, i.e. as if the form doesn't have a submit button, as well as without using JS. I would like to know if there is any way to do this, and where I can learn more about this form behavior. I can't find information about this anywhere, even on w3.org.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in many ways,

best one is with tabindex to prevent tab reach this button -

```
<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;" tabindex="-1" />
```

Also you can hide your button link this. or you can go with java script function like this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Using jQuery.

$(function() {
    $('form').each(function() {
        $(this).find('input').keypress(function(e) {
            // Enter pressed?
            if(e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
                this.form.submit();
            }
        });

        $(this).find('input[type=submit]').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```